# Multiplying Variables Not Alerting

Tags: javascript

I have a script which calls variable values from input fields and multiplies them, 
At the minute my function isnt executing, Im getting no alert neither, I think this is because of my if statement, can anybody see whats going wrong?

```
function Calculate() {

    var ContentMinutes = document.getElementById ("ContentMinutes").value;
    var ContentMinutesSelect = document.getElementById('ContentMinutesDD')
        .options[document.getElementById('ContentMinutesDD').selectedIndex].value

    if (ContentMinutesSelect == 0.0166)
    {
        var RenderingHours = 10;
        var VideoHours = 5;
        var VideoSeconds = 1;
        document.getElementById("RenderHours").innerHTML=RenderingHours;
        document.getElementById("VideoHours").innerHTML=VideoHours;
        document.getElementById("VideoSeconds").innerHTML=VideoSeconds;
    }
    else if (ContentMinutesSelect == 0.0003)
    {
        var RenderingHours = 1540;
        var VideoHours = 54;
        var VideoSeconds = 1;
        document.getElementById("RenderHours").innerHTML=RenderingHours;
        document.getElementById("VideoHours").innerHTML=VideoHours;
        document.getElementById("VideoSeconds").innerHTML=VideoSeconds;
    }
    else
    {
        var RenderingHours = 6410;
        var VideoHours = 345;
        var VideoSeconds = 124;
        document.getElementById("RenderHours").innerHTML=RenderingHours;
        document.getElementById("VideoHours").innerHTML=VideoHours;
        document.getElementById("VideoSeconds").innerHTML=VideoSeconds;
    }


    var NoOfFrames = document.getElementById ("NoOfFrames").value;
    //var EstimatedCoreHours = document.getElementById ("EstimatedCoreHours").value;
    var ServiceLevel = document.getElementById('SerivceLevelDD')
        .options[document.getElementById('SerivceLevelDD').selectedIndex].value;
    var RenderHours = 1;
    var CoresInTest = document.getElementById ("CoresInTest").value;

    var EstimatedCoreHours =  GetNumeric(NoOfFrames) 
        * GetNumeric(RenderingHours) 
        * GetNumeric(CoresInTest);

    var EstimatedTotal =  GetNumeric(ServiceLevel) 
        * GetNumeric(EstimatedCoreHours);

    alert('Estimated Cost = '
        +EstimatedTotal.toFixed(2)
        + 'Estimated Core Hours = '
        +EstimatedCoreHours);

    document.getElementById("EstimatedCoreHours").innerHTML = 
         EstimatedCoreHours.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("EstimatedTotal").innerHTML = 
         EstimatedTotal.toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById("EstimatedCoreHours").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    document.getElementById("EstimatedTotal").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
}

function GetNumeric(val) {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat(val))) {
        return 0;
    }
    return parseFloat(val);
}
```

Comment: Try going to http://jslint.org, paste your code into the textarea, and click 'jslint'.

Comment: It helps greatly if you reduce your code to the minimum that reproduces the error. In doing so, you will often find the solution. If not, post it here.

Comment: If we don't know what the value of ContentMinutesSelect is we cant check what the problem is... can you give us a link to the page you're trying this on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (ContentMinutesSelect == 0.0166)` i think when you do .value you will get string result.

So your comparision should be

`if (ContentMinutesSelect == "0.0166")`

Comment: Didnt seem to work, Cant think of why the script isnt working

Comment: Irrelevant, if one expression is a number, the equals operator will force the other expression to number.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will display no alert if any line before it results in an error , like if there isn't an element with the id 'ContentMinutes' in your document . The best way to debug would be to use something like firebug , or you could always put in a bunch of alerts and figure out what goes wrong.